# Gearman Workers disconnect periodicaly

Tags: php, gearman

I've been running a Gearman Job Server with multiple workers which get called multiple times a day (10k+ x an hour) without any issues.

I recently added 3 new workers that aren't called that often (3-6 x a Day). It seems that the new workers disconnect from the gearman server at what appears to be random (sometimes once a day, sometimes after they finish a job), but leave the PHP process running, meaning there are no FATAL errors, they only become unavailable as gearman workers.

The error log is mostly correct, however i saw the following warning on one of the logs:
Warning: GearmanWorker::work(): flush(Connection timed out) send -> libgearman/connection.cc:847

I couldnt find anything related to this issue and wanted to ask a couple of question:

1) What is this error referring too? a Worker timeout i.e a job took too long? or a Server timeout meaning it was idle for so long that it disconnected from the Gearman Server? Is there anything that could be fixed by using GearmanWorker::setTimeout to -1?

1.1) If i do not explicitly set the timeout, is ther a default timeout by gearman?

2) Should gearman workers be restarted periodically?

3) Can this be related to the return value of the worker? I alway return boolean, would a "false" disconnect the server?

Note: Unlike my other workers, this workers are being called by the clients as "do background"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: After detecting such connection error, did you tried with a retry to connect attemp?

Comment: No, is that something i need to set up on the workers? I will try it and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself recently and couldn't find a solution.  Thought I would post my fix for the next person to find this page.  In the worker code, I added a check to while loop for a timeout condition, and force it to exit the script:

```
while($worker->work() || $worker->returnCode() == GEARMAN_TIMEOUT)
{
  if($worker->returnCode() == GEARMAN_TIMEOUT)
  {
    echo "Timeout.\n";
    exit(0);
  }

}
```

Then I keep the worker script running with Supervisor.  When the supervisor process detects that the script has died, it starts it back up again automatically.  No more issues with workers disconnecting.  It's not very elegant, but it got the job done.

Comment: I am running worker through cli and if while is there how will you run 50-100 workers

Comment: @Naveen Agarwal The PHP script itself is the worker, so you configure supervisor to spin up multiple copies of your PHP script.  As long as you have enough RAM and CPU you can fire up as many as you want.  CLI is good for testing *one* worker, but you will need a tool like supervisor to run 50-100 at a time.